# What is contained on pages 180-199 of the Inverse World book?

Tags: inverse-world

I have heard good things about Inverse World and in reading the product description on DriveThruRPG, I found the following sentence:

> The playbooks for Inverse World (Captain, Collector, Golem, Lantern, Mechanic, Rainlord, Sky Dancer, Survivor, and Walker), as well as all content on pages 180-199, are under the Creative Commons CC-BY-SA License: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/

A quick check of the creative commons license site gives this human readable summary:

> #### You are free to:
>
> **Share** — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format
>
> **Adapt** — remix, transform, and build upon the material
> for any purpose, even commercially.
>
> #### Under the following terms:
>
> **Attribution** — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made. You may do so in any reasonable manner, but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use.
>
> **ShareAlike** — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original.
>
> **No additional restrictions** — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits.

I have found a PDF that contains the playbooks, mount and vehicle rules, and compendium classes. I have two questions from this:

- Are the mount and vehicle rules and compendium classes part of the CC content in pages 180-199?
- What else is contained in those pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## pp180-199 is the New Rules chapter

The subchapters are **Restock**, **New Tags**, **Aspects and Drives**, **Alternate End of Session Move**, and **Mount and Vehicle Rules**.

Comment: I'm not going to type in all 20 pages, but if local standards allow, and there is demand, I can provide a little more detail.

Comment: Nah, if people want detail it'd be fine to discuss more, but that'd be best done in another question.  The only thing you're missing is an explicit statement as to the licensing of the content.

Comment: The licensing information in the PDF is as the OP states. I'm not sure what I can add to it.